# Python array based alternative to GRASS r.cost

Tags: python, grass-gis, numpy, array, rioxarray

I am looking for a numpy array based alternative to the [GRASS r.cost](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass78/manuals/r.cost.html) function.

I have a friction surface raster where the value of each cell corresponds to travel time. I would like to find the cells within *n* travel time of a user specified cell, so essentially the cumulative sum in multiple directions until the max travel time is achieved. I have written a PyQGIS script that does this using the GRASS r.cost function (specifying the max cost) which works well.

However, eventually this procedure will be part of a bigger Python (not PyQGIS) script where rasters are ingested using rioxarray and then processed as numpy arrays. I know that I can use GRASS here as well, but I'm wondering if there is a simpler alternative? I would like to minimise barriers for users, ideally they will not need to install GRASS or QGIS. I've been searching fruitlessly for options...

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

For those with the same issue, I am now using the [gdistance package](https://pypi.org/project/gdistance/) with good results.

Note that for r.cost the input raster values should refer to the time taken to traverse the whole cell.

For gdistance the input raster values should correspond to minutes required to move a metre in that cell.

Answer (score 0):

This is not exactly the same but it may be helpful for some people (especially those with dependency issues relating to GDAL.

```
def count_connected_ones(arr):
    # Create a structuring element for 8-connectivity
    struct = generate_binary_structure(2, 2)

    # Label connected components
    labeled_arr, num_labels = label(arr, struct)


    # Replace the original ones with the maximum values
    d = {0:0}
    for i in range(1,num_labels+1):
        d[i] = np.count_nonzero(labeled_arr==i)

    
    
    
    
    lookup_func = np.vectorize(lambda x: d.get(x, x))

    # Apply the lookup function to the array
    result = lookup_func(labeled_arr)

return result
```